# Why when using backgroundworker to read files from hard disk sometimes the program freeze hold?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openpop

I think the reason is that it's reading/loading each file from the hard disk some files size are 8.5MB
I'm using OpenPop to load eml(emails) files i downloaded and saved from my pop3 email provider.

Now on the hard disk i have over 7000 eml files some 8.5MB some 23KB

```
int countUploadMsg = 0;
        private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            allLoadedMessages = new List<OpenPop.Mime.Message>();
            OpenPop.Mime.Message loadedMessage = null;
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"e:\testmail\");
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                loadedMessage = OpenPop.Mime.Message.Load(file);
                allLoadedMessages.Add(loadedMessage);
                counter += 1;
                int nProgress = counter * 100 / files.Length;
                backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(nProgress);
            }
        }
```

For sure the problem is with this line:

```
loadedMessage = OpenPop.Mime.Message.Load(file);
```

With the Load part of the OpenPop library.

So maybe it's taking time it's not that fast i tried but i didn't find so far a faster eml files reader/parser.

My question is why if the code is inside the DoWork event of the backgroundworker sometimes the program stop/freeze for few seconds on some files ? Isn't it should work smooth using backgroundworker ? Maybe longer time but why the program freeze sometimes ? I'm using backgroundworker for the Load but it seems that sometimes it's reading the files from the hard disk and make the program freeze until it's finishing reading the current file it is on.

Comment: Please add the code that launches the background worker, and any code that is in the work completed or progress events of the background worker.  Everything in the background worker should be running in a separate thread as you mentioned.

Comment: If your backgroundworker is used correctly, that should not happen. Did you try it on different machines and with the files not being at the same drive as your system? Maybe it's not only your app, but the whole system that slows down because your causing so much hard drive traffic. ...probably not, just guessing

Comment: I think i know what is the problem. The problem at first is when i click on the ListView control column on one of them there is 3 columns. I did that when i click on a column it will sort the items. I guess when i click on one of them it make it slow or freeze. The progress in the dowork event is keep on working the column i clicked on is freezing. I checked now if i click on other buttons it's working smooth. So what i need is to solve the sorting mechanism.

Comment: Should i ask another question about the sorting or edit this question ? I have an idea what to do but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that OpenPOP's MIME parser is slow (and it is [according to my own benchmarks](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeParserBenchmark)), you could try switching to my [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) library which is significantly faster (i.e. more than 25x faster) than OpenPOP.